# gfortran optimization causes fortran do-variable loop error during runtime

Tags: optimization, iterator, fortran, do-loops

I have written a fortran routine that uses some legacy fortran 77 code for finite elements. However, with a particular mesh, when the -O optimization flag is turned on, an important do-loop iterator is somehow being modified, even though fortran supposedly prohibits this. I have compiled this code using gfortran4.5 with the -fcheck=do run-time checking enabled and it has verifies what I've noted above. A runtime error occurs, only when optimizations are turned on and points directly to the do-iterator.

Using gdb on optimized code seems (while it seems erratic - lines bouncing back and forth) seems to clearly indicate that the do-iterator somehow gets set back to zero, and essentially this causes a nice infinite loop.

Any suggestions as to how to hunt down and fix whatever is causing this bug would be greatly appreciated, as I'd like to make sure the whole project can be consistently compiled with the same flags.

Comment: Can't offer much insight without some code, preferably a small testcase that reproduces the problem.    An obvious question, though, is -- have you run things through valgrind or something similar to see if there are any memory overwrites?   It may be that you're (say) going past the end of an array, and in the un-optimized code you stomped on something harmless, but with a changed memory layout you're now stomping on the do-loop iterator.

Comment: the source of the do-loop in question?

Answer (score 4):

You say that you use fcheck=do; why not go all the way and use fcheck=all? What you're seeing sounds like a typical case of memory corruption due to an array bounds violation, which fcheck=all can in some cases catch. Where the array bounds checking doesn't work that well is with implicit interfaces and incorrect bounds being passed; a solution here is to put your procedures into modules, allowing the compiler to check interfaces.

And, like Jonathan Dursi said, consider using a tool like valgrind.

Comment: I guess for the time being I will just run it in debug mode. The fortran code I'm interfacing to uses C for dynamic memory allocation and was originally written in f77. Using valgrind and fcheck=all , the program errors out well before my problem (probably highlighting other issues with the code). I chose fcheck=do, because the do-loop variable is getting modified, and it's causing an infinite loop (resetting j=1 to j=0). The strange thing is the same code, when optimized runs fine with tetrahedra finite element (probably different layout) than hexahedral brick finite elements where it fails.

Comment: If the program causes errors with valgrind and fcheck=all, I certainly wouldn't trust the results.